# При установке pyaudio через pip3 : fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kali-linux

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyaudio ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4d33c_bk/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp8uwqh_90pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-LpWKty/python3.6-3.6.5~rc1=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
   #include "portaudio.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4d33c_bk/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-sffwppv9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-LpWKty/python3.6-3.6.5~rc1=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
     #include "portaudio.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4d33c_bk/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-sffwppv9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4d33c_bk/pyaudio/
```

При установке libportaudio2:

```
sudo apt install libportaudio2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libportaudio2 is already the newest version (19.6.0-1).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.